# Can't create an AVD manager

Tags: java, android

I have installed the Android Development Tools and Android SDK but I can't create an AVD Manager. 
I have tried selecting different options in the Create new Android Device Manager, but when I hit OK nothing happens. Console prints these error messages:

```
[2014-06-18 22:02:23 - SDK Manager] Error: null
```

And this, also:

```
[2014-06-18 22:27:05 - SDK Manager] Warning: Couldn't open file: /Users/eduarddedu/.android/devices.xml (No such file or directory)
```

I have ARM EABI v7a System Image installed and I am not using any spaces in the name field.

I have also tried running  monitor.bat as someone suggested; the Android Device Manager start-up screen briefly appeared, but then I got an error message saying an error has occurred and 'See the log file: /Users/...

I opened the log file and it says:

java.io.IOException: The folder "/Users/eduarddedu/.android/monitor-workspace/.metadata" is read-only.

This is really weird because there isn't any folder .android in /Users/eduarddedu. I used ls -a to view hidden files.

I don't know if this is relevant but I also discovered that the Android SDK Manager log reports these two errors:

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: File not found

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml, reason: File not found

That's it. Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: What OS are you using? This sounds like it might be a permissions issue.

Comment: You need to change the permission of the .android and .metadata files so that you can write to them.

Comment: You are probably right but I can't find the android directory. I know it's supposed to be located in my home folder so I have tried ~/.android but I get No such file or directory.

Comment: Mavericks doesn't allow users to create folders at top levels of the file system and maybe that's why the .android folder is missing. Anyone with the same issue?

Comment: From your error messages, it should be at `/Users/eduarddedu/.android/`. If the directory doesn't exist, perhaps that is the issue. Try creating this `.android` folder manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I can create AVDs now. To create an AVD, android attempts to write files in the home folder of the current user. In my case, the home folder was not writable. I logged in as root and changed the owner of the home folder from 'staff' to me, using the chown command. Here is an excellent tutorial on how to do this in a bash shell : gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0070.html